# its showing a warring that sender is not accessed! and same with **kwargs and when I login as admin my profile page shows the details about the admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals, django-sessions

"""I'm unable to access senders and **kwargs and this is my signals.py file and I guess is causing a bug that is when I login as admin its start showing admin details in my profile page too, please help me out as I'm new to Django"""

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


 
def save_profile(sender, instance,**kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

[image]

[image]

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

the below image is of apps.py here is its showing users.signals is not accessed
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxE5m.png

Comment: why are you creating two signals instead of one ?

Comment: from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


#@receiver(post_save, sender=User) #Should i remove this?
def save_profile(sender, instance,**kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()

Comment: yes remove the last function and try it.

Comment: you can access the admin page only if your either staff,superuser,..,this means that the current user has no right to access the admin.the `testuser` can not access the admin page untill you give him the permission.

Comment: yes i tried but stuck with the same problem

Comment: have you tried the admin account ?

Comment: `when I login as admin my profile page shows the details about the admin` i think it should work like that. what is the problem with this ?

Comment: but it automatically logouts the current user for an e.g testuser

Comment: yes it worked like that.try to open an other tab in incognito mode log as testuser  and the other (non incognito ) open as admin user.you will be abble to see both page.

Comment: the session of a user is related to the browser

Comment: yes its resolved now, Thank You buddy :)

Comment: you are welcome happy coding ))

Comment: Please don't insert code screenshots next time! Use code formating instead.